# Wrong offsetWidth when switching between Angular components

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, html5-canvas

To resize the canvas to the current element size, I use the following HTML:

```
<div #canvasContainer class="canvas-container">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

This makes it possible to query the size of the `canvasContainer` with offsetWidth and offsetHeight to then set the size of the canvas element. For this I use the [Fabric library](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js) and the command where `canvas` is a `fabric.Canvas` object and `this` is an Angular component.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Sets the canvas dimensions during the initial render
  console.log(this.canvasContainer.nativeElement);
  this.canvas.setDimensions({
    width: this.canvasContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth,
    height: this.canvasContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight
  });
}
```

The problem is that when switching between components, the offsetWidth of the canvasContainer is smaller than the actual width. I assume this is the width of the scrollbar since the difference between the canvas width and the div container width lie between 15px for Chrome to 12px in Firefox.

When resizing the window with the window:resize callback, the offsetWidth is correct as well as when inspecting the console log of the nativeElement even during the component switch.

What is the best way to fix this?

The source code of the component can be found on [Github](https://github.com/FlowLeaf/flow-leaf-server/tree/add-fabric-canvas/planner/src/app/components/fabric-canvas).

[image: Screenshot of canvas element in div container]

Comment: Why aren't you using `ngStyle` to dinamically assign width and height of your div?

Comment: Did not know ngStyle, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Something like: `<div class="your-class" [ngStyle]="{'height.px' : aTsVariable}">`

Comment: Setting the width is possible with the ngStyle method, but the source of the value I use is still wrong (this.canvasContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth/offsetWidth) and using @ViewChild('canvasContainer') canvasContainer: ElementRef;

Comment: Looking your image you want the canvas element to have with/height as the div container, if I understood it right. Am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly. This also works when resizing or reloading the page. Only when switching from a different component (Canvas Aspects / Team) to the Floor Planner component is the width wrong. A work around is to use a delayed callback to set the width.

Comment: Since the div container has always the right dimensions you could just giveto `<div #canvasContainer class="canvas-container">` width and height at 100%, same for the `canvas`, it should work

Comment: Had to use a 10ms setTimeout after the ngAfterViewInit to fix it. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am having a similar issue and currently resorting to a 10m settimeout as well. Im sure there is a better fix.